# Printing Web Page Without Print Preview

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

How can I get a code to print a page using `js`.

Note: I don't want to take print preview and then print. - once I click, it should print the page.
Page is containing text and image.
I need to have a link for printing the current page.
Once I click it should fetch the data and print.
(without showing content in nextpage as print preview and then requesting to press print option)

using: `window.print()` 
its getting me to print preview page and I have to press print option from browser - right!
I need to print once I click or during page load.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible. Security reasons come to the mind - it would mean the peripherals of the computer are directly accessible from the web page code.

Comment: There is no way from which i can do this?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, it is not possible to start a client's printer from a web page.